# Count character ocurrences in a string in MSBuild

Tags: string, msbuild, msbuild-4.0

What's the easiest way to count the number of times a character ('\' in my case) appears in a string using MSBuild? I tried using Split(`\`) to no avail.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MsBuild 4.0 allows the use of property functions http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd633440.aspx

You can use this to split the string. You must then substract the length by 1 to get the occurrence count.

```
<Target Name="SplitCount">
    <PropertyGroup>
        <path>test\document\home</path>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <PropertyGroup>
        <test>$(path.Split('\').length)</test>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <Message Text="occurrence count: $([MSBuild]::Subtract($(test), 1))"><Message>        
</Target>
```

Comment: yep, this is perfect! Thanks very much indeed!

Answer (score 1):

In the [MSBuild Community Tasks](http://msbuildtasks.tigris.org/), there is a RegexMatch task that would give you a list, which you could then count perhaps.

Another option would be to write your own custom task.  Then add a bit of Linq like so:

```
string input = "This \\ is \\ a \\ test";
var items = (from c in input where c == '\\' select c).ToList();
var count = items.Count;
```

Comment: I use the MSBuild Community tasks, so that would probably be better. How would one go about counting the items on that list?